# Quiero convertir condigo a c#

Tags: java, c#

Este codigo estaba en java y lo fui traduciendo de poco a c# sin embargo hay una parte que no logro traducir o implementar , que es Arrays.toString...mis arreglos deben ser int y bueno me dice el error que deben ser tipo object, ya nose que hacer para que se vea el numero que esta dentro del arreglo .............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] nodo_inicial = new int[4];
        int[] nodo_actual = new int[4];
        System.Collections.Stack nodo_frontera = new System.Collections.Stack();
        IList<object> nodos_visitados = new List<object>();

        int contador_pasos = 0;

        nodo_frontera.Push(nodo_inicial);
        while (nodo_frontera.Count > 0)
        {
            nodo_actual = (int[])nodo_frontera.Pop();
            contador_pasos++;
            Console.WriteLine("Nodo actual: " + Arrays.ToString(nodo_actual));
            if (nodo_actual[0] != nodo_actual[1] && nodo_actual[0] != nodo_actual[2] && nodo_actual[0] != nodo_actual[3] && nodo_actual[1] != nodo_actual[2] && nodo_actual[1] != nodo_actual[3] && nodo_actual[2] != nodo_actual[3] && nodo_actual[0] != 0 && nodo_actual[1] != 0 && nodo_actual[2] != 0 && nodo_actual[3] != 0)
            {
                if ((nodo_actual[0] + 1) != nodo_actual[1] && (nodo_actual[0] + 2) != nodo_actual[2] && (nodo_actual[0] + 3) != nodo_actual[3] && (nodo_actual[1] + 1) != nodo_actual[2] && (nodo_actual[1] + 2) != nodo_actual[3] && (nodo_actual[2] + 1) != nodo_actual[3])
                {
                    if ((nodo_actual[0] - 1) != nodo_actual[1] && (nodo_actual[0] - 2) != nodo_actual[2] && (nodo_actual[0] - 3) != nodo_actual[3] && (nodo_actual[1] - 1) != nodo_actual[2] && (nodo_actual[1] - 2) != nodo_actual[3] && (nodo_actual[2] - 1) != nodo_actual[3])
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("SOLUCION: " + Arrays.toString(nodo_actual));
                        Console.WriteLine("Número de pasos: " + contador_pasos);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            nodos_visitados.Add(nodo_actual);
            int i;
            for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                int[] nodo_temporal = new int[4];
                int x;
                for (x = 0; x <= 3; x++)
                {
                    nodo_temporal[x] = nodo_actual[x];
                }
                int j;
                for (j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
                {
                    if (nodo_temporal[j] == 0)
                    {
                        int num = 0;
                        switch (i)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                num = 4;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                num = 3;
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                num = 2;
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                num = 1;
                                break;
                        }
                        nodo_temporal[j] = num;
                        bool? existe = false;
                        for (int pos = 0; pos < nodos_visitados.Count; pos++)
                        {
                            if (nodos_visitados[pos] == nodo_temporal)
                            {
                                existe = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if ((!existe).Value)
                        {
                            nodo_frontera.Push(nodo_temporal);
                            Console.WriteLine("Nodo añadido a frontera: " + Arrays.toString(nodo_temporal));
                            j = 4;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Puedes usar [este metodo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19148534/579895) para sustituir Arrays.ToString que no existe en .net

Answer (score 0):

Una de las opciones es esta:

```
string[] values = ...;

string concatenado = string.Join(",", values);
```

Fuente:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245581/does-array-tostring-provide-a-useful-output